# Searching for item SKU in Commerce orders

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, search, relatedto

I'm trying to show some Commerce 2 order information on the front-end. I can't work out the correct syntax. I'm trying to list orders that include a specific product.

I have orders for item SKU "abc123" but this is returning no results.

```
{% set myOrderQuery = craft.orders()
    .relatedTo("abc123")
    .limit(10)
    %}

{% set orders = myOrderQuery.all() %}

{% if orders|length %}
  <ul>
    {% for order in orders %}
      {% for item in order.lineItems %}
        <li>{{ item.sku }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% else %}
  <p>No results</p>
{% endif %}
```

If I remove the .relatedTo parameter I get results including orders for that item. How do I just return orders that include that item?

I've tried various permutations of `relatedTo` and search but haven't found anything that works yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `hasPurchasable` order query param:

https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/dev/element-queries/order-queries.html#haspurchasables

```
{% set myOrderQuery = craft.orders()
    .hasPurchasables(product.defaultVariant)
    .limit(10)
%}
```

Comment: Just what I needed, that's working. Thanks Luke